# Set a custom html template for a specific shipping method?

Tags: magento2, template, shipping-methods

While creating a custom shipping method works great, how to set up a specific template for specific shipping method in the checkout?

Seeing the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` there is a `shippingMethodItemTemplate` set to `Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item`.

I believe i need to change this somehow for my custom shipping method but leaving others untouched, how can i accomplish that?

Do i need to create a mixin for `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` and set the template for the custom shipping method?

My goal is to add a select tag for that specific shipping method, the save data afterwards i have it covered, i think.

Comment: Just wondering, have you found a solution?